# Create a Json object from a list in C# controller

Tags: c#, jquery, json, model-view-controller

I have been trying to get a Json data defined based on a string list from the Controller MVC c# for quite some time with no luck. I think I am missing something silly, but can you please guide me here?

I have a controller function returning a view with Viewbag assigned as below :

```
   List<string> Brands;
        Brands = GlobalVariables.Brands.Where(m => m.brand_cd != "OOO" && m.brand_cd.Trim().ToLower().Equals(m.main_brand.Trim().ToLower()))
                 .OrderBy(m => m.brand_cd).Select(m => m.brand_cd.Trim()).Distinct().ToList();



        ViewBag.BrandList = Json(Brands);
```

And In my view I am trying to define a Json varible as

```
<script>
    var brandList = '@ViewBag.BrandList';
</script>
```

But this isnt helping. I get a string in the result. Any ideas ?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Why you want to do that?

Comment: '*I get a string in the result*' - what exactly do you think `JSON` is?

Comment: Start by removing the `'` that makes it a string.  You may also need to use `Html.Raw` - `var brandList = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.BrandList)`;

Comment: Thank you guys, one of our members asked me to do this and it worked like magic. I was not rendering it appropriately in the view file.

<script>
    var brandList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.BrandList));
</script>

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a JsonResult object and expecting to get a JSON string out, which is not the case.

To get actual JSON into the ViewBag you will need to serialize your object and place it in the ViewBag then.

Example by using the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package, which is fairly standard:

```
string myJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Brands);
ViewBag.BrandList = myJsonString;
```

And in the view:

```
<script>
    var brandList = @ViewBag.BrandList;
</script>
```